# xcode swift 4 number increase animation?

Tags: swift

i am trying to animate UILabel number increase in `swift 4` , i am still new with this language, what i am trying to do is :

```
for index in 1...500 {
   self.lbl_counter.text = "\(index)"
}
```

the value always 500 .

i have tried this also

```
 for index in 1...500 {
DispatchQueue.main.async{
       self.lbl_counter.text = "\(index)"
}
    }
```

> what did i miss here to make it animate increasing the numbers ?

Comment: you can use timer which increments the label value in specific time.

Comment: Could be off-topic but, I'd suggest to check: https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel

Comment: @AhmadF exactly what i want  , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    /// Label
    private var customLabel : UILabel?

    /// MAximum Count to which label will be Updated
    private var maxCount : Int?
    /// Count which is currently displayed in Label
    private var currentCount : Int?
    /// Timer To animate label text
    private var updateTimer : Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        customLabel = UILabel()
        customLabel?.textColor = .black

        /// Add label to View
        addConstraints()

        /// Start Timer
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.maxCount = 100
            self.currentCount = 0
            self.updateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func updateLabel() {
        self.customLabel?.text = String(currentCount!)
        currentCount! += 1
        if currentCount! > maxCount! {
            /// Release All Values
            self.updateTimer?.invalidate()
            self.updateTimer = nil
            self.maxCount = nil
            self.currentCount = nil
        }
    }

    func addConstraints(){
        /// Add Required Constraints
        self.view.addSubview(customLabel!)
        customLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customLabel?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        customLabel?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        customLabel?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        customLabel?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but it should be fast like rewarded coins

Comment: Just reduce the Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, Time to 0.15 instead of 1 or more less as much fast you want the text value to be changed

Comment: updating value depends on timer CallBack Reduce the timer Time and Value will be updated at more faster rate

Answer (score 1):

What you currently write assign the last number of the loop 500 to the label's text as there is no delay between setting the numbers from 0 to 500

```
for index in 1...500 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5 * Double(i) ) {
      self.lbl_counter.text = "\(index)"
    }
}
```

// OR

```
 let timer  = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (t) in

        self.lbl_counter.text =  "\(self.lbl_counter.tag)"

        lbl_counter.tag += 1

        if lbl_counter.tag == 501 {

            t.invalidate()
        }

    }
```